# Как кликнуть по свёрнутому сайдбару

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

есть вопрос. Пытаюсь кликнуть по-свёрнутому сайдбару, но почему-то выдает ошибку `element not interactable`. При это м если я открываю сайдбар, тогда такой код работает

Вот код элемента в `HTML`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код теста:

```
@Test
    void testLoginAtlasDiagnostic() {
        ChromeDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.CHROME).setup();
        WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(1440, 920);
        wd.manage().window().setSize(dimension);
        wd.get("link");

        wd.findElement(By.id("email"));
        WebElement userEmail=wd.findElement(By.id("email"));

        wd.findElement(By.id("password"));
        WebElement userPassword=wd.findElement(By.id("password"));


        WebElement login = wd.findElement(
            By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__layout\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/form/button"));




    userEmail.sendKeys("login");
    userPassword.sendKeys("pass");
    login.click();


    /*WebElement openSidebar = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app-sidebar-1\"]/div/div[1]/button"));
    openSidebar.click();*/


    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement openAgencyProf = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app-sidebar-1\"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));
    openAgencyProf.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сначала подскроллить к элементу, а потом уже кликать по нему

```
WebElement element = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app-sidebar-1\"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));
((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```